Update Notion Database (table) by Row ID
I'm trying to sync data between a DB (for advanced analytics) and Notion (as operational front end).  Today I can grab all Notion data and push into the DB, no problem.
I would like to now push changes from the DB into Notion.  I can identify the changes in the DB, and I would like to use Notion's Row UUID (captured from the above sync) to ensure I'm updating the correct row in Notion.
The first problem: I can't figure out how to structure the JSON filter object for the API call so that I'm getting back a row by the notion "ID" for that row (page?).  Is it possible, or should I use that to pull back the Page object instead?
Here's my filter.  The API function works fine for larger pulls, its really this JSON filter object I'm struggling with:
This works:
    notion_filter = {"filter": {
                        "property": "Description",
                        "rich_text": { "contains": "Cross-Team" }
                        } }

All of these error with "400 Client Error: Bad Request for url":
    notion_filter = {"filter": {
                        "id": { "equals": notionrow_id }
                        } }

    notion_filter = {"filter": {
                        "id": "id",
                        "id": { "equals": notionrow_id }
                        } }

The name and type both appear as "id" just not sure how to structure the JSON.
Any hints would be appreciated -- Thanks!!
